# Energy Function Expansion in Deform by Laplacian Coordinates

Tags: laplacian, minimal-surfaces, deformation-theory, meshing, coordinates

I am currently working on the strain energy function for a particular graph.

The paper I am currently referencing is "Spatial Relations Preserving Character Motion Adaptation".

I am asking because I do not understand the formula of the thesis.

The formula is:

$E_L(V_i') = \sum_{j}\frac{1}{2}\left\|\delta_j-L(p'^i_j) \right\|^2 = \frac{1}{2}V_i '^TM_i^TM_iV_i -b_i^TM_iV'_i+\frac{1}{2}b_i^Tb_i $

In the formula above, $p$ represents the vertex $(x,y,z)$ at frame i.
$M$ represents the Laplacian matrix and $b$ represents the Laplacian coordinates.

At this time, when there are 5 vertices, $V$ becomes a $5X3$ matrix, $M$ becomes a $5X5$ matrix, and $b$ becomes a $5X3$ matrix.

The matrix calculation shows the values of the final energy function in the form of a $3X3$ matrix. However, in order to minimize a function, I think it should come out in scalar form.

If you want matrix calculations to be displayed in scalar form, you can convert them to $1X15$ form ($V_i = (p_1^T...p_5^T)$) by swapping the elements of $V$. However, in this case, the Laplacian matrix $M$ must be derived in the form of $15X15$, and the Laplacian matrix is regarded as a square matrix according to the number of vertices.

I think $M$ is a specific matrix that has been modified, or I think that $x$, $y$, $z$ of $V$ should be separately processed when performing matrix calculation. I'd appreciate it if you could point out where I'm wrong about matrix calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The norm could probably be the Forbenius Norm. You can find this paper, "Optimal Step Nonrigid ICP Algorithms for Surface Registration", for details of how the norm of a matrix is calculated to minimize the energy term. The Forbenius Norm is to calculate the norm of a matrix $\textbf{A}$. It is given by:
$$||\textbf{A}_{m\times n}||^2 = \sum_m\sum_n|a_{ij}|^2$$

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).